# How to delete multiple values in JSONB array Postgresql array object

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a JSONB array below

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "age": "21",
    "phone": "6589",
    "town": "54"
  },
  {
    "name": "test12",
    "age": "67",
    "phone": "6546",
    "town": "54"
  },
  {
    "name": "test123",
    "age": "21",
    "phone": "6589",
    "town": "54"
  },
  {
    "name": "test125",
    "age": "67",
    "phone": "6546",
    "town": "54"
  }
]
```

Now I want to delete the object if the name is test or test125. How to delete multiple or single values in JSONB array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update statement including a subquery, which eleminates the unwanted elements with `NOT IN` operator and aggregates the rest by using `jsonb_agg()` function, would find out this operation :

Choose this :

```
 1. UPDATE tab
       SET jsdata = t.js_new
      FROM 
          (
           SELECT jsonb_agg( (jsdata ->> ( idx-1 )::int)::jsonb ) AS js_new
             FROM tab
            CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata)
             WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
            WHERE j->>'name' NOT IN ('test','test125') 
          ) t
```

or this one :

```
 2. WITH t AS (  
               SELECT jsonb_agg( (jsdata ->> ( idx-1 )::int)::jsonb ) AS js_new    
                 FROM tab   
                CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata)   
                 WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)   
                WHERE j->>'name' NOT IN ('test','test125')  
               ) 
        UPDATE tab    
           SET jsdata = js_new   
          FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=eb49176fb9927bc63d4c574087b59ca7)</kbd>

Comment: tried this solution working for me. Thank you @Barbaros Özhan

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Postgres 12, you can use `jsonb_path_query_array` function to filter the `jsonb` here is the sample for your question:

```sql
with t (j) as ( values ('[
  {"name":"test","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test12","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}, 
  {"name":"test123","age":"21","phone":"6589","town":"54"},
  {"name":"test125","age":"67","phone":"6546","town":"54"}
]'::jsonb) ) 
select jsonb_path_query_array(j,
  '$[*] ? (@.name != "test" && @.name != "test125")')
from t;
```

more info on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that does that:

```
create function remove_array_elements(p_data jsonb, p_key text, p_value text[])
  returns jsonb
as
$$
select jsonb_agg(e order by idx)
from jsonb_array_elements(p_data) with ordinality as t(e,idx)
where t.e ->> p_key <> ALL (p_value) ;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = remove_array_elements(the_column, 'name', array['test', 'test125'])
where id = ...;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=157351fee170f5514f13e54259840d2a)

Comment: function remove_array_elements(jsonb, unknown, integer[]) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type.  geting this error

Comment: update "calorieTracker" 
  set "caloriesConsumption" = remove_array_elements("caloriesConsumption" , 'c_id', array[21])
where c_id = 40

Comment: You are passing an *integer* array, not a `text` array.

Comment: In remove_array_elements I am passing the_column is my JSON so i am getting this error array ERROR: column "21" does not exist
  Position: 116